# Retrieve Object Value from Java Map using Map Key

Tags: java

I'm trying to sync to user list by building a map that contains a username as a key and an user object as the value. Once the map has been built, I'm having difficulties retrieving the object values. Below is the code I'm using.

```
private Map<String, User> map = new HashMap<String, User>();
```

I'm populating the map key and object as followed.

```
        List<User> users = session.createCriteria(User.class).list();

        for(ApplicationUser user : users) {
            map.put(user.getUserName(), user);
        }
```

I'm trying to retrieve the data as followed,

```
        List<Person> persons = session.createCriteria(Person.class).list();
        for (Person p : persons) {
            User user = map.containsKey(p.getUsername()) ? map.get(p.getUsername()) : new User();
            //Email is always null. 
            System.out.println(user.getEmail());
        }
```

Could someone help point me in the right direction on how to retrieve the object values from my map. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should change your loop to this:

```
   for (Person p : persons) {
        String username = p.getUsername();
        User user = map.get(username);
        if (user != null) {
           System.out.println(user.getEmail());
        } else {
          System.out.println("User " + username + " is unknown");
        }
    }
```

Then set a breakpoint in the loop and debug your code. It looks correct so far. Maybe you are just not setting `email` in `User` or the users from `persons` are not in your `map`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on the code cleanup, however it doesn't seem to resolve my issue :( In the first loop, I tested to see that the object was in fact loaded into the map and contained an email. My output statement showed the email. In the second loop, it appears the user is being found in the map and isn't null, but does not contain an email. Any suggestions?

Comment: @George: Well, if it doesn't contain an email then the user might have no email set in the database. Take the debugger and check the values of `users` after you loaded them from the database.

Comment: The user does have an email in the database, when I initially set the email in the first loop, I can retrieve it while still in the first loop using the same code used in loop two. Both of these loops are called from the same method too. The object that contains the email within the hashmap is somehow losing all it's values by the time it makes it to loop two.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say, our second database field values weren't populated which caused our insert to delete the primary database's values resulting in this mess. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like email is null because you are not initialising email in the default constructor of User() which gets executed here :

> User user = map.containsKey(p.getUsername()) ? map.get(p.getUsername()) : new User();

Here , i think the usernames that you put in the map does not match with those you try to retrieve in the second part of the code . i.e . map.containsKey(p.getUsername()) seems to return false and default constructor gets called with email as null .

Try printing out the(or debug inspect) the map keyset() and the person usernames and check if they match exactly .

Comment: unfortunately this isn't the issue. My map contains all the keys that match exactly with my Person username.

Answer (score -1):

@George I think you will get a nullpointer exception if the user doesn't belong to person.

```
 System.out.println(user.getEmail());
```

when condition is false User user = new User(); user.getEmail() is null

Comment: Have you tested this? System.out.println(null) works fine, it just prints null.

Comment: I haven't tested this... that's why I wrote 'I think you will get a nullpointer...'